# Ring modulator with matlab

Tags: modulation, dsp, amplitude-modulation

I'm a bit newbie in DSP. I'm trying to modulate two signals and create DSB-SC am signal. I choose ring modulator for it. So can anyone show me any working ring modulator circuit?

Comment: What has matlab got to do with this?

Comment: Try [this simple diode modulator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/502152/unable-to-generate-am-wave-using-opamp-log-antiog-multiplier/502173#502173) to get a basic understanding of how ring modulators work. This isn't a suppressed carrier circuit, it's just a straightforward AM broadcast type modulator.

Comment: actually Matlab has nothing to do with it, but I am doing simulation in Simulink so that why I told it.

Comment: Why do you have the word "matlab" in your title then? Did the link help?