# FET AM modulator

Tags: circuit-design, modulation, fet, amplitude-modulation

I have been meddling with a FET-based AM modulator. I implemented a basic circuit as attached here along with its output. Is the output as it should be? If not, what am I doing wrong, and how can I make the necessary changes?

[image: FET AM Modulator]

[image: FET AM Modulator Output]

---

All thanks to Mr. Andy AKA and Mr. Glen Geek. I have re-implemented the FET AM Modulator. Please, see if it is OK now!
[image: FET AM Modulator]

[image: FET AM Modulator Output]

Comment: A little less carrier amplitude would help.

Comment: Sure sir, will do that. Thank you very much.

Comment: You have two answers and, to finish this question and answer session, you should formally accept one of the answers as per instruction [on this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour). Of course if you have more relevant comments to make, please go ahead.

Answer (score 3):

> *I implemented a basic circuit as attached here in photo along with its
> output. Is the output as it should be?*

That output looks like ordinary A + B (rather than A × B) and, if I examine your circuit, indeed that is what it is (a summing amplifier). Of course there may be a tiny amount of "A × B" lurking in the overall signal but, for producing amplitude modulation, it is highly (if not totally) inefficient.

> *what am I doing wrong, and how can I make the necessary changes?*

I'll suggest a diode multiplier (the simplest form of "double sideband plus carrier" amplitude modulation) as a solution: -

[image]

This is a 1 MHz carrier AM modulator and can be received on a standard AM radio receiver in the MW band: -

[image]

[image]

Images can be found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/633144/voltage-modulation-circuit/633149#633149) or [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/502173/20218).

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! I surely missed loads! Forgot in theory it is A x B not A + B.

Comment: I just tried it on Multisim! God! It is working like a charm! Thank you Mr. Andy AKA, sir!

Comment: @AwaisMushtaq --> [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) --> remember that this simple modulator only performs "radio broadcast" amplitude modulation. If you require full double-sideband-suppressed-carrier, it becomes both more complex to generate and more complex to receive.

Answer (score 3):

Both N-channel JFET and diode modulators are possible. In this digital age, you might note that the carrier signal (in this case 100 kHz) is a square wave...it might be generated from a logic gate or some other digital source.
[image: schematic JFET modulator, Diode shunt modulator]
Be aware that this is a very non-linear modulator, whose output resistance varies. As in Andy's circuit, a linear buffer stage should follow (high input impedance, low output impedance). Buffering and filtering are not shown here.
These are both shunt modulators, where the JFET or diode short the analog signal to ground for half-a-cycle of the digital carrier signal. Many harmonics are generated, which must be attenuated with a selective (inductor/capacitor) resonator.
[image: FFT JFET modulator (purple), diode modulator (green)]
The diode modulator has superior performance, with far less distortion. The difficult-to-suppress distortion products at 98 kHz and 102 kHz are well-attenuated in the diode modulator; the JFET modulator attenuates these distortion products less-so.
I have shown a 100kHz modulator rather than AM radio signals at 1MHz because LTspice simulations run faster at lower carrier frequencies. Since circuit impedances for the diode modulator are lower than JFET modulator, circuit performance at high carrier frequencies should be superior for the diode modulator.

---

Note that this kind of digital modulator could substitute an open-collector or open-drain transistor for **V5 + series D1**...something like 74HC05. A microcontroller with GPIO set for open-drain should work well, however R3 might be made somewhat larger-value.