# Name for this kind of mixer?

Tags: digital-logic, rf, analog, radio

I am trying to learn how a gilbert cell could be used as an amplitude modulator and tried to simplify its operation by assuming single ended inputs. While trying to visualize some concepts I inadvertently made this mixer. It is an active mixer(?) but it doesn't seem like a full switching mixer.
[image]

The non-LO input is clipped into a square wave similar to a switching mixer, but there is no transistor saturation involved. Q2 is biased to work best at 1mA Ic; the max square wave voltage through the base of Q1 allows ~1mA Ic to flow through Q2. When the square wave is on the falling edge, Q2's Ic gets choked off. I imagine this is equivalent to connecting/disconnecting an oscillator from ground at a frequency to mix with.

I have never come across a mixer/modulator of this style and wonder why that is/how such a mixer could be categorized.

[image]

Edit: Simplified and cleaner circuit, thank you for the suggestion @Andyaka
[image]

Comment: Label your nodes that you wish to display because at the moment the node numbers are meaningless. I've seen a single ended mixer used this way. You deprive the top transistor of collector current and force it to operate in the saturation region where the slope of the I/V curve is modulated. Mind you; your graphs show no sign of modulation as far as I can tell (even if I don't know what circuit nodes they connect to).

Comment: @Andyaka aka Thanks for pointing that out, I added node labels and showed the modulated result

Comment: You need to show the modulating signal rather than the demodulated output.

Comment: @Andyaka is n004 (turquoise colored) what you are referring to? Interesting note on the single ended mixer you mentioned, seems to describe what happens here too. Feel free to post as an answer.

Comment: Well you have a complex circuit producing a not-very-nice looking modulated carrier and, the signal that is important to look at is the signal that causes the carrier modulation rather than the poor looking demodulated output. You might want to compare your result with my less-complicated circuit: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/650896/20218

Comment: @Andyaka Impressively clean output! Is that just a buffered and filtered single diode mixer?

Comment: Yes it is but, like most modulators you need some kind of filter on the output.

Comment: @Andyaka You have answered my question and more. Thank you for that. Feel free to turn your comment(s) into an answer.

Comment: A Gilbert-cell can indeed do an AM modulator. But in its fully balanced form, it is a double-sideband-suppressed-carrier modulator. To do standard AM modulation, you have to add a DC offset to a Gilbert cell *modulation input port* so that the carrier appears.

Comment: @glen_geek Great point, I didn't consider the effect of balanced inputs on a gilbert cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a single ended mixer used this way. You deprive the top transistor of collector current and force it to operate in the saturation region where the slope of the I/V curve is modulated.

But the real test is showing the modulation signal and the resulting modulated carrier like I did in this simple AM modulator: -

[image]

This is a 1 MHz carrier AM modulator and can be received on a standard AM radio receiver in the MW band: -

[image]

> *@Andyaka Impressively clean output! Is that just a buffered and
> filtered single diode mixer?*

Yes it is but, like most modulators you need some kind of filter on the output.