# Demodulator circuit design

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, mosfet, current

[image]
**Below is Triangular Modulation Output of a Triangle input wave**
[image]
**Below is weird Modulation Output of a Triangle input wave when it is connected to demodulator**
[image]

[image]

The **modulator circuit is quoted from Andy** at [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/502152/unable-to-generate-am-wave-using-opamp-log-antiog-multiplier/502173#502173)

HI all, I have been trying to understand modulation and demodulation circuitry as part of my hobby:)

The modulation circuit above works fine but when I connect the output of the modulator to the demodulator (as shown by blue arrow), **the output of the modulator turns bad (Shown above) although I buffered it using op-amp as shown** in circuit and the **demodulator does not produce any output** (The output should be a triangular wave) .

The **demodulator chip circuitry** is I built from Texas Instruments at [here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers-group/amplifiers/f/amplifiers-forum/894838/tina-ti-newbie-stupidity) and I followed the demodulator circuit at [here](https://fotoelektronika.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/ta7642-spice-model.pdf). Does anyone know how to correct this? I attached my LT Spice  **asc** file in [google drive here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kYX8cO0uXwyyu29J9JNhhh-KK5xIShek/view?usp=sharing) for correction.

Edit: I have sucessfully demodulated the signal as shown by the graph. But, I just wanna try to simulate the TA7642 from [here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/amplifiers-group/amplifiers/f/amplifiers-forum/894838/tina-ti-newbie-stupidity) because the chip offers better modulation :)

Thank you and have a nice day ahead

New update:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you start with a simple diode-capacitor-resistor envelope detector circuit instead of trying to mimic the TA7642?

Comment: @Andyaka, hi sir, I have sucessfully demodulate it after learning the envelop detector :) , but I just wanna simulate the TA7642 chip because it offers better modulation. Not sure what is wrong with my LT SPice model :) see the edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use a simple diode-capacitor-resistor demodulator like this: -

[image]

> *I just wanna simulate the TA7642 chip*

The maximum sensitivity of the [TA7642](https://cxem.net/tuner/files/tuner93_TA7642.pdf) is about 600 μV hence you are driving the input about a thousand times too hard and, of course, it will just produce garbage on the output. Remember that the 7642 is a radio receiver and cannot be expected to deal with anything over 600 μV at its input. I suggest you pot-down the output from the modulator by 1000:1.

However, the data sheet circuit cannot be relied upon for creating a successful spice model; it's there to show the general working principle of the chip. In other words, there's a significant chance that the original manufacturer will be protecting their IP somewhat but, good-luck.

Comment: HI Andy, I decide to try your circuit on breadboard :), just wondering, the transmitter(modulator circuit in your diagram) has a 300u inductor as an antenna. However, for your receiver circuit, it does not have an inductor probably? May I know what modifications to your circuit diagram if I want to transmit the triangle signal wirelessly and that would be interesting :)

Comment: Use a wire antenna where V2 is and break the link to C2 then attach the open end of C2 to a similar wire antenna.

Comment: Hi sir, do you means at the Vout node, we break it to attach 2 antenna, 1 at the receiver and 1 at transmitter:) ?

Comment: Is the wire antenna you mean as my above picture, just 1 polarity ?

Comment: You should stop editing your question right now. You are not using the site correctly. There are ways to post a picture that can be shown in comments without affecting your question. I'm rolling back your question to how it was.

Comment: [Try this but any problems and you should raise a new question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATePU.png)

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your reply. Does the common modern LF356N op-amp with 5MegaHertz Bandwidth is suitable to handle the 1MegaHertz wave in your diagram?

Comment: Only suitable if you use a supply voltage of at least +/- 5 volts. But, you will want amplification and with a bandwidth of only 5 MHz, the maximum gain will be limited to 5 at 1 MHz. If I were you I'd ask a new question about how to pick an op-amp that is suitable for higher gain at 1 MHz.

Answer (score 4):

> But, I just wanna try to simulate the TA7642 from here because the
> chip offers better modulation.

The TA7642 I.C. schematic from https://cxem.net/tuner/files/tuner93_TA7642.pdf shown below.

[image: TA7642 LTspice schematic]

LTspice's default NPN transistor is used in the simulation. It is an ideal transistor with very little frequency limitations.

- A 1.5V DC voltage source provides power.
- A 600-ohm earphone with a little internal inductance is a load.
- Input is driven with two current sources...one provides DC bias plus 1MHz, the other provides zero bias, but adds 1.002 MHz signal to "simulate" modulation. Note that AM modulation is not sinusoidal with this method, but does give modulation useful to test AM demodulators.
  The 600 ohm earphone  output is R16+L1.

---

Edit: added LTspice transient run. v_out is voltage from 600-ohm resistor (simulating headphone load) to GND.

[image: LTspice Transient plot (input current), V_output)]

Comment: Hi sir, what is the purpose of the inductor 0.005H seems big? I am quite surprised that this chip can have an input voltage sensitivity of  600 μV, which seems to be undetectable by other normal chips haha :)

Comment: @jessicasmith I have guessed at a headphones' internal inductance...it may not be necessary for the simulation. There are a LOT of transistors in this chip. It is possible to do something similar with ONE transistor (with great care)...look into *regenerative receiver*. A regen receiver is a complicated beast - understanding how it demodulates requires a very good understanding of its non-linear operation.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to simulate your circuit. See my new post on top. The output blue signal is very weak. Is it supposed to be like that? :)

Comment: LTspice's default NPN transistor differs from a 2N2222. Your simulation with 2N2222 is not a good one. I have added the demodulated waveform to my answer.

Comment: @jessicasmith I had erronously entered R14 as 74k rather than 74.6 ohms. It made a significant difference to transient run (Re-did LTspice transient plot). Had to reduce AC input amplitude quite a bit - now 200pA. Included 1MHz base current in transient display.